# SwiftUI - making multiple paths with different colored strokes scale in a view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have a view that shows points on a path object and scales the points to fit the dimensions of whatever view it is in, and it looks like this:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let frame = CGRect(x: geometry.frame(in: .local).minX, y: geometry.frame(in: .local).minY, width: geometry.frame(in: .local).width, height: geometry.frame(in: .local).height)
            
            Path { path in
                for line in drawingToShow.visibleLines {
                    DrawingViewTools().add(line: line, to: &path)
                }
            }
            .scaled(for: frame)
            .translateToCenter(for: frame)
            .stroke(.black, lineWidth: lineWidth)
            .frame(alignment: .center)
            
        }
```

And I am using this code as a modifier for my "translateToCenter" modifier:

```
extension Path {
    
    func scaled(for rect: CGRect) -> Path {
           // if path is bigger in width
           let scaleX : CGFloat = (rect.width * 0.98) / boundingRect.width
           let scaleY : CGFloat = (rect.height * 0.98) / boundingRect.height
           let scale = min(scaleX, scaleY)
           return applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)).offsetBy(dx: -boundingRect.origin.x * scale, dy: -boundingRect.origin.y * scale)
       }
    
    func translateToCenter(for rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let centerFrameX = rect.size.width / 2
        let centerFrameY = rect.size.height / 2
        // center of the boundingRect

        let offX = centerFrameX - (boundingRect.width / 2.0)
        let offY = centerFrameY - (boundingRect.height / 2.0)
        return applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 1)).offsetBy(dx: offX, dy: offY)
    }
    
}
```

However, I am now using strokes with multiple colors. Is there any way to set the strokes so they display the same (scaled to fit the view), but each stroke can be its own path object colored by a different .stroke modifier?  I tried the code below but it is simply stacking all of the paths on top of each other:

```
            ZStack {
                ForEach(Array(drawingToShow.visibleLines.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, line in
                    Path { path in
                        DrawingViewTools().add(line: line, to: &path)
                    }
                    .scaled(for: frame)
                    .translateToCenter(for: frame)
                    .stroke(line.color), lineWidth: lineWidth)
                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                }
            }
```